# MySQL: Get the MIN value of a table from all columns & rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Refer this [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c61/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c61/4) (a table with multiple columns (decimal)).

And I want to get the minimum value skipping `0` zero values from all cells in that table.

I tried this sql

```
SELECT
LEAST(
MIN(IF(sgl_ro=0,'NULL',sgl_ro))
,MIN(IF(sgl_bb=0,'NULL',sgl_bb))
,MIN(IF(sgl_hb=0,'NULL',sgl_hb))
,MIN(IF(sgl_fb=0,'NULL',sgl_fb))
) AS MinRate
FROM room_rates
WHERE hotel_id='1'
GROUP BY hotel_id;
```

But it gives me wrong value (I think because of multiple rows. It returns the correct value if one row).

Thanks.

Comment: In what way is the the result wrong, can you give an example when the result is wrong, and what it should have been?

Comment: @Lennart As you can see the sqlfiddle result, it returns `10.50`. But I want `9`

Comment: `'NULL'` IS NOT NULL (it is a string) `N U L L` [without spaces]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
SELECT least(MIN(nullif(sgl_ro,0))
            ,MIN(nullif(sgl_bb,0))
            ,MIN(nullif(sgl_hb,0))
            ,MIN(nullif(sgl_fb,0)) ) as min_rate
FROM room_rates
WHERE hotel_id='1'
;
```

EDIT: Use NULL instead of 'NULL'

'NULL' is a string and MySQL have very weird ideas on how to cast between types:

```
select case when 0 = 'NULL' 
            then 'ohoy' 
            else 'sailor' 
       end 
from room_rates;

ohoy
ohoy
ohoy
```

I.e. you solution will work fine by removing the ' from NULL:

```
SELECT
LEAST(
MIN(IF(sgl_ro=0,NULL,sgl_ro))
,MIN(IF(sgl_bb=0,NULL,sgl_bb))
,MIN(IF(sgl_hb=0,NULL,sgl_hb))
,MIN(IF(sgl_fb=0,NULL,sgl_fb))
) AS MinRate
FROM room_rates
WHERE hotel_id='1'
;

MINRATE
9
```

Edit: Comparison between DBMS:

I tested the following scenario for all DBMS availible in sqlfiddle + DB2 10.5:

```
create table t(x int);
insert into t(x) values (1);
select case when 0 = 'NULL' 
        then 'ohoy' 
        else 'sailor' 
   end 
from t;
```

All mysql versions returned 'ohoy'

sql.js returned 'sailor'

all others (including DB2 10.5) considered the query to be illegal.

Edit: handle situation where all columns in a row (or all rows for a column) = 0

```
select min(least(coalesce(nullif(sgl_ro,0), 2147483647)
                ,coalesce(nullif(sgl_bb,0), 2147483647)
                ,coalesce(nullif(sgl_hb,0), 2147483647) 
                ,coalesce(nullif(sgl_fb,0), 2147483647) ) )  
FROM room_rates
WHERE hotel_id='1'
  AND coalesce(nullif(sgl_ro,0), nullif(sgl_bb,0)
              ,nullif(sgl_hb,0), nullif(sgl_fb,0)) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: don't use a string, try `MIN(IF(sgl_ro=0,9999,sgl_ro)) as x` instead it then behaves as you would expect. I think every this is getting evaluated as string that's why you get '1' as first character not '9'

Comment: THere is no guarantee that 9999 wont be the smallest number, NULL is better (not 'NULL')

Comment: quite true, I used it only to show that `'string'` isn't good, it's a comment designed to help (not the answer)

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for the well explanation. But Your solution not work when there is a column that having `0` for all rows. It just returns `(null)` as the min value. What is the solution for such situation?
[Please refer this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1f11/1)

Comment: In that situation, what should the answer be?

Comment: It's issue with `LEAST`: it returns NULL if any argument is NULL

Comment: @Lennart The lowest value of the table. In this case, `15` should be the MinRate. @rims answer bellow is correct. But I would like to try to modify the above `sql` to return the correct value. Can someone try this?

Comment: I've added another answer, 0 is mapped to null which in turn is mapped to maxint. To avoid maxint as an answer rows where all columns quals 0 is filtered.

Comment: Filtering expression can be without calls to any functions: `AND NOT (sgl_ro = 0 AND sgl_bb = 0 AND sgl_hb = 0 AND sgl_fb = 0)`

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for your responses. Great help. But since in here, have to write twice the same col name in your solution, I think @rims solution is better coz in my actual situation Im having `12` columns to deal with. But again, thank you.

Comment: Just beware that with 12 columns you will be accessing the table 12 times in rims solution. For a small table it might not matter but as the table grows this can have an impact on performance.

Comment: @Lennart you are suggesting that your solution is fast? I'm just asking for knowing.

Comment: It accesses the table only once so it is likely to perform better than a query that accesses the table 12 times, but the only way to find out for sure is to investigate the two solutions. Explain the queries and also measure the time each of them uses.

Comment: @Lennart You are correct. I found some differences between two queries even accessing 4 columns and 3 rows. So I'll make your answer as Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution step by step:

*Get min value from one column:*

```
SELECT MIN(sgl_ro) AS MinRate, hotel_id
   FROM room_rates
   WHERE sgl_ro != 0 AND hotel_id='1'
   GROUP BY hotel_id
```

*Get min values from all columns and aggregate to one min value (final query):*

```
SELECT MIN(MinRate) AS MinRate
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(sgl_ro) AS MinRate, hotel_id
     FROM room_rates
     WHERE sgl_ro != 0 AND hotel_id='1'
     GROUP BY hotel_id
  UNION 
  SELECT MIN(sgl_bb) AS MinRate, hotel_id
     FROM room_rates
     WHERE sgl_bb != 0 AND hotel_id='1'
     GROUP BY hotel_id
  UNION 
  SELECT MIN(sgl_hb) AS MinRate, hotel_id
     FROM room_rates
     WHERE sgl_hb != 0 AND hotel_id='1'
     GROUP BY hotel_id
  UNION 
  SELECT MIN(sgl_fb) AS MinRate, hotel_id
     FROM room_rates
     WHERE sgl_fb != 0 AND hotel_id='1'
     GROUP BY hotel_id
  ) res
GROUP BY hotel_id
```

Test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b156/1